# A strange error of 'let' in bash

Tags: bash

I wonder if the code below has wrong syntax ?

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
let "time_used = 1 - 1"
echo $time_used
```

When I run it, nothing print. The script died on `let "time_used = 1 - 1"`.

If I remove `set -e` in second line, I get the correct result `0`.

Why it happened?

Comment: See: `help let`

Comment: You could figure out by trying for non-zero cases, like `let "time_used = 2 - 1"` in which case you would see `echo` output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

let is a [bash built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins) for shell arithmentic

```
let "time_used = 1 - 1"
```

is equivalent to

```
(( time_used = 1 - 1 ))
```

however 0 in shell arithmetic means false and gives error exit status to avoid to exit with `-e` `|| true` can be added after command

```
(( 0 )) || true
let "time_used = 1 - 1" || true
```

`|| true` allows to "bypass" `-e` option for commands returning an error exit status however we can't distinguish a command that failed from a command that returns a false exit status. Other option can be to use arithmetic to return always a truthy value.

```
(( (time_used = 1 - 1) || 1))
```

Comment: OP is using `set -e`.

Comment: It does not! see the other answer

Comment: ok, i was updating my answer

Comment: Thanks very much.  Why is it designed to be like this? Is this a bad design?

Comment: `-e` option is not the default, it seems more tedious but it is better to explicitely exit on error for each command: `command to check || exit 1` can be sufficient because generally a failing command writes message on stderr otherwise to add a specific message defining a function `command || exit_fail "message" `

Comment: it is the design because an arithmetic expression can be used in a for or while loop or in if then elif else statement,also it is not specific to bash but for all posix shells

Answer (score 3):

Because `let` returns `1` if it's result is equal `0`.
In other case, it returns `0`.

> $ help let | tail -n2
>       Exit Status:
>       If the last ARG evaluates to 0, let returns 1; let returns 0 otherwise.